# Cumulative Sum DataFrame (.groupby())

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get the cumulative sum of 'counter' over the years. Basically, adding the sums for each individual year while maintaining the multi index structure. Help is highly appreciated! :)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df_raw[['counter']])
df['listings_per_zip'] = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
df = df.mean(level=[0,1])
```

[Curren Input (df_raw)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fay8D.png)

[Current Output (df)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IRZy.png#)

(Example) Expected output: Sum for ZIP over the years. For instance, 2018 'listings_per_zip' should be the sum of 2008+2009+...+2017

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks! I've now provided the current output and an explanation for the expected output.

Comment: ... `.cumsum()` ?

Comment: @rafaelc I have tried to use that before, however, it somehow messes up the sum. Taken .cumsum() results in lower sum for 2018 than regular sum would which in this case is unrealistic.

Comment: Current output is not much useful without the current input.

Comment: @Valentino Thanks! Input is now included as well. In short, just individual rows per ZIP and YEAR, which are then grouped in the code provided. However, I'm unable to group them and output the cumulative sum of values per ZIP/YEAR-combo.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved by the following code:

```py
df['listings_per_zip'] = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().groupby(level=[1]).cumsum()
```